# $f(x,y):=\int_{a}^{xy}g(t)dt$ and $h(x,y):=\int_{y}^{x}g(t)dt$. Find $f'$ and $h'$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed and that $f(x,y):=\int_{a}^{xy}g(t)dt$ and $h(x,y):=\int_{y}^{x}g(t)dt$. Find $f'$ and $h'$.

---

I don't know how I could apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for $f$ or $h$. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean with $f'$?

Comment: Shouldn't that be a partial derivative?

Comment: it must be total derivative

Comment: @ErginSuer Do you mean the [differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)?

Comment: @GitGud Yes, I want to find the linear transformations corresponding to derivative of f and h

Comment: @ErginSuer As you can see on the wikipedia link, the differential is built from the partial derivatives. Can you find them?

Comment: @GitGud the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ is $yg(xy)$. Right?

Comment: @ErginSuer Right, exactly as it is done in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find $f'$ and $h'$, first compute the first order partials.

$$f_x = g(xy) \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xy) = y\cdot g(xy)$$

$$f_y = g(xy) \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(xy) = x\cdot g(xy)$$

$$h_x = g(x)$$

$$h_y = -g(y)$$

Therefore

$$f' = \begin{pmatrix} y\cdot g(xy) & x\cdot g(xy)\end{pmatrix}$$

$$h' = \begin{pmatrix} g(x) & -g(y)\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I am not very well in calculus. Did you use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find $f_x$?

Comment: Yes. I used the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule to find $f_x$. Note $f(x,y) = H(u)$, where $H(u) = \int_a^u g(t)\, dt$ and $u = xy$. Hence, by the chain rule, $f_x = H'(u) u_x$. By FTC, $H'(u) = g(u) = g(xy)$. Also, $u_x = y$. Therefore $f_x = y g(xy)$.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, suppose that we have a function $F$ defined by $$F(x)=\int\limits_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(t)\,\mathrm d t=\int\limits_0^{b(x)} g(t)\,\mathrm d t-\int\limits_0^{a(x)} g(t)\,\mathrm d t$$
Then $F(x)=G\circ b(x)-G\circ c(x)$ with $G(x)=\int_0^x g(t)\,\mathrm d t$, so $$F'(x)= b'(x)G'(b(x))-a'(x) G'(a(x))=b'(x)g(b(x))-a'(x)g(a(x))$$
by the chain rule and (one of) the fundamental theorem(s) of calculus.

Can you find suitable definitions of $a$ and $b$ and $F$ to calculate the partial derivatives that you need? Note that 
$$f'(x,y)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y),\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\right)$$
and similarly for $h$